# How to use sqlcmd to execute many queries in one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have many SQL scripts; I want to execute them in one table using `sqlcmd`.

I have created a new database and a new table. How can I read several files from my PC and execute them in one table?

Comment: What have you already tried? [see this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sqlcmd -S hany-PC\hany -d CentralFinance -i C:\1.sql

Comment: to make it clear (hany-PC\hany =  server name)   + (CentralFinance = db name) + (dbo.News.Table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this

```
1.Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Accessories, and then click Notepad.

2.Copy and paste the following Transact-SQL code into Notepad:

USE <DBName>;
GO
select *from table1
select *from table2
select *from table3
select *from table4
select *from table5
--give all your select query here
GO

Save the file as myScript.sql in the C drive.

3.To run the script file

4.Open a command prompt window.

In the Command Prompt window, type: sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql

Press ENTER.

The result of the sql file is written to the command prompt window.
To save this output to a text file

5.Open a command prompt window.

In the Command Prompt window, type: sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql -o C:\EmpAdds.txt

Press ENTER.

No output is returned in the Command Prompt window. Instead, the output is sent to the EmpAdds.txt file. You can verify this output by opening the EmpAdds.txt file.
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can easily do this with SQLS*Plus from the command line:

SQLS>@script001

SQLS>@script002

SQLS>@script003

SQLS>@script004

You can also create a master script that contains calls to all these scripts.

FYI:

I wrote SQLS*Plus in my free time, this is a cool tool for SQL Server that is helpful to tons of DBAs, especially with the Oracle background - it is like Oracle SQL*Plus but for SQL Server.

Tool is great for DBAs (I shared some of the received feedback on the web site), much better than SQL Server sqlcmd and also great for the command line reporting and automation. There is a 100% free version for the business users.

Already got few great clients around the world using it in production. One client, for example, moved lots of Oracle SQL*Plus reports to SQL Server in just a couple of hours.

It is on https://www.sqlsplus.com